# Fragment Page stack count always 0 in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to go back to the previous fragments when click back button. If there is no pages available in page stack it should show press back again to exit.

I am trying like this.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            int pageCount = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
            if (pageCount != 0) {
                this.getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                return true;
            } 
            else
            {
                 if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
                        super.onBackPressed();
                        return true;
                    }

                    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
                        }
                    }, 2000);
            }
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Here I check the page count. But it always showing 0.

I always add this line in all `fragment.replace`

```
FragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
```

Please help me to resolve the problem. When I click the back button It should go to the previous page. If there is no pages is available mean it should show the toast message.

Comment: Make sure you are not mixing FragmentManager and SupportFragmentManager.

Answer (score 0):

> Try it, Use fragment.add instead of fragment.replace. it will allow to
>   maintain your all Fragments to back stack. If you are using
>   fragment.replace then it will maintain only one fragment in stack.
>
> Sample Code:

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    HelloFragment hello = new HelloFragment();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, hello, "HELLO");
                    fragmentTransaction..addToBackStack("optional tag");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: I try with add() also. Still the page Count is 0.

Comment: make sure you are not using same TAG with all fragments fragmentTransaction.add. in my sample code its "HELLO"